# PHP Combine Arrays into Multidimensional and Render into HTML Table

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have some PHP arrays that i get from DB and need to be combined so I can render it into a HTML table view. But I'm not sure about the best way to get it done.
Here's my arrays structure.

```
ArrayA = array(
         0 => array(
              "ID" => 1,
              "FullName" => "John Doe",
              "BloodType" => "B"
         ),
         1 => array(
              "ID" => 2,
              "FullName" => "Patrick Star",
              "BloodType" => "AB"
         )
);
ArrayB = array(
         0 => array(
          "ID" => 1,
          "UserID" => 1,
          "CHECKUP" => "1ST_MONTH",
          "Remarks" => "ABCDE"
         ),
          1 => array(
          "ID" => 2,
          "UserID" => 1,
          "CHECKUP" => "3RD_MONTH",
          "Remarks" => "FGHIJ"
         ),
         2 => array(
          "ID" => 3,
          "UserID" => 2,
          "CHECKUP" => "1ST_MONTH",
          "Remarks" => "KLMNO"
         ),
         4 => array(
          "ID" => 4,
          "UserID" => 1,
          "CHECKUP" => "1ST_MONTH",
          "Remarks" => "PQRST"
         )
);
ArrayC = array(
         0 => array(
              "ID" => 1,
              "UserID" => 1,
              "DonorDate" => "2020-12-01",
              "Height" => 180,
              "Weight" => 70,
              "RiskScore" => 4
         ),
         1 => array(
              "ID" => 1,
              "UserID" => 2,
              "DonorDate" => "2020-12-01",
              "Height" => 160,
              "Weight" => 50,
              "RiskScore" => 10             
         )
);
ArrayD = array(
         0 => array(
          "ID" => 1,
          "UserID" => 1,
          "Visit" => "Visit 1",
          "Remarks" => "ABC"
         ),
          1 => array(
          "ID" => 2,
          "UserID" => 1,
          "Visit" => "Visit 2",
          "Remarks" => "CDE"
         ),
         2 => array(
          "ID" => 3,
          "UserID" => 2,
          "CHECKUP" => "Visit 1",
          "Remarks" => "FGH"
         )
);
```

I want to render it into an HTML table like this.

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Blood Type</td>
      <td>Full Name</td>
      <td>1st Month</td>
      <td>2nd Month</td>
      <td>3rd Month</td>
      <td>Donor Date</td>
      <td>Height</td>
      <td>Weight</td>
      <td>Risk Score</td>
      <td>Post Visit 1</td>
      <td>Post Visit 2</td>
      <td>Post VIsit 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>ABCDE</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>FGHIJ</td>
      <td>2020-12-01</td>
      <td>180</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>CDE</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>PQRST</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>AB</td>
      <td>Patrick Star</td>
      <td>KLMNO</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2020-12-01</td>
      <td>160</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>FGH</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So, is it possible or maybe is there any alternative solutions? Please note that the arrays have big dataset.

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach loop inside another for loop to get the elements.

```
for ($i=0 ; $i < count($ArrayA); $i++) {
  foreach ( $ArrayA[$i] as $k => $m) {
      if($k == 'ID')
          echo "<td>$m</td>";
      else
          echo "<td></td>";
  }
}
```